# Symfony security - How to detect and block "data flooding"

Tags: php, symfony, security, doctrine-orm

I am working on a `Symfony` + `Doctrine` based project which is basically an online address book / ToDo list: Users create an account to manage any number of address book records and/or ToDo list items.

One possible thread scenario could be, that some script/bot is used to automatically create a large number (thousands, millions, ...) of new entries within a short period of time. This would not only effect the current performance of the WebApp during such an attack but also slow/block the WebApp due to the large size of the database.

Is there any existing feature in `Symfony` and/or `Doctrine` (build-in or as third-party extension) that might help to detect such attacks (e.g. observe number of new entities per minute) and block them?

Of course I could implemented this myself, but as with all security features, I would prefer existing and well tested solutions.

Is there a special name for such attacks? Using "data flooding" as keyword did not bring up any suitable results.

**EDIT:**
@zerkms added the question, if this actually is an attack. In my opinion it is. Sure, is is *just a use of app features* but isn't it obvious, that automatically adding thousands or more new entries to flood the database with junk is a malicious abuse of this feature? Requesting a page thousands of time is also *just a legit us of features*, but still it is an DOS attack.

Additional @zerkms pointed out, that one simply need the limit the number of entries. This is obvious, but the question was **how to this**.

Sending a mail is no big deal but the swift mailer bundle makes it a lot easier and straight forward. Using `curl` to communicate with the `PayPal Rest API` is not hard, but using the SDK and all its existing functions is even simpler.

Likewise adding a simple `COUNT` statement is not a big deal either. But is this the *best* solution? Where do I actually perform the count? Manually when creating or persisting a new entity? By creating a custom repository subclass, that does this transparent for there rest of the code? Do I use a timestamp to limit the entries per time or is there a better way? Maybe there is already a build in function in Symfony or Doctrine?

I **don't** think, that this is the most complex or difficult question ever. But I **don't** that the answer is obvious and not worth discussing either.

Comment: So limit the number of stored items per user to reasonable minimum, then extend on demand? "special name for such attacks?" --- is it even an attack :-S

Comment: Of course it is an attack. DOS is also "just a very large number of normal requests"... Of course limiting the number of stored items a solution, but the question is how to do this. Are there any build in / tested solutions or has it to be implemented manually?

Comment: Just a single query with `COUNT` following by a check. Why do you need a "solution" for that? PS: it's not DOS for sure.

Comment: A lot of different entities, different possible solutions (event listeners, custom repository, doctrine annotations, etc.) with different pros and cons... No need to reinvent the wheel if there are build in and **tested** solutions. Sure, this is not the most complex problem ever, but still not as easy as *"just add a `COUNT` and a check"*. This kind of answer is not helpful at all.

Comment: It is as easy as that. You're finding a problem where there is no one. The fact that you cannot find anything to "solve" it should give you a hint for that. I'm not insisting though, it's fine you think it's a "rocket science" to count number of rows in a table.